# Displaying markers in map with Ajax - ChartJS

Tags: jquery, ajax, chart.js

I am currently working with a vector map generated by chartJS from devexpress. In order for the map to generate markers in a map it needs to get the values from a JSON object. I am able to get these markers to display if the variables are hard coded in the jquery function. Following a similar steps with other working graphs, I am passing the json values from the ajax call  to `markers` in the function but I am not getting any markers displayed in the map. I read the [FULL](http://chartjs.devexpress.com/Documentation/Tutorial/Configure_VectorMap) documentation but cant get it to work. How can I load the markers values through an ajax call?

Map

```
$.getJSON('../graph_json/location.php', function(dataSource) {
$('#acadamy_by_state').dxVectorMap({
        mapData: DevExpress.viz.map.sources.usa,
        //dataSource: dataSource,
        markers: dataSource,

        bounds: {
            minLon: -135,
            maxLon: -65,
            minLat: 20,
            maxLat: 60
        },
        zoomFactor: 1.25,

        background: {
            color: 'paleturquoise'
        },

        areaSettings: {
            customize: function (area) {
                if (jQuery.inArray(area.attributes.name, mostPopulatedStates) != -1) {
                    return {
                        color: 'forestgreen'
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        markerSettings: {
            customize: function (m) {
                return {
                    text: m.attributes.name
                }
            }
        }
    })
});

});
```

graph_json/location.php

```
[{
    coordinates: [-121.2808, 38.3320],
    attributes: {
        name: 'Sacramento'
    }
}, {
    coordinates: [-97.75, 30.25],
    attributes: {
        name: 'Austin'
    }
}];
```

Comment: Can you provide us with jsfiddle example?

Comment: Check the `dataSource` argument value. Is it the array of `{ coordinates: [...], attributes: {...} }` objects?